# django setting variable SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER with heroku

Tags: django, http, ssl, heroku, django-settings

I am trying to set variables related to https/ssl on django 1.8 with heroku. but in Django 1.8 tutorial, it saids that i should be careful setting this variable expecially "SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')"

In django 1.8 tutorial it saids

> Warning
>
> You will probably open security holes in your site if you set this
>   without knowing what you’re doing. And if you fail to set it when you
>   should. Seriously.
>
> Make sure ALL of the following are true before setting this (assuming
>   the values from the example above):
>
> - Your Django app is behind a proxy.
> - Your proxy strips the X-Forwarded-Proto header from all incoming requests. In other words, if end users include that header in their
>     requests, the proxy will discard it.
> - Your proxy sets the X-Forwarded-Proto header and sends it to Django, but only for requests that originally come in via HTTPS.
>
> If any of those are not true, you should keep this setting set to None
>   and find another way of determining HTTPS, perhaps via custom
>   middleware.

And when i use heroku does if fulfill all these conditions? Should i keep going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yep - you should be fine - see the heroku docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers