# redirect http to https safely for Heroku app

Tags: django, heroku, https, http-redirect, django-settings

I am trying to redirect my Django + Heroku app from `http` to `https`, but I am surprised that I did not find any **safe** and straightforward way.

[According to Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls):

> ### Issue
>
> You have configured an SSL endpoint and now you want your application
>   to use https for all requests.
>
> ### Resolution
>
> Redirects need to be performed at the application level as the Heroku
>   router does not provide this functionality. You should code the
>   redirect logic into your application.
>
> Under the hood, Heroku router (over)writes the X-Forwarded-Proto and
>   the X-Forwarded-Port request headers. The app checks X-Forwarded-Proto
>   and respond with a redirect response when it is not https but http.
>
> ...
>
> **Django**
>
> Set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` to `True`.

So it must be done at Django. [This is the most complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26670053/5802289) I found, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663670) is also similar.

> Django 1.8 will have core support for non-HTTPS redirect (integrated
>   from
>   [django-secure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#security-enhancements)):
>
> ```
> SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
> SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
> ```
>
> In order for `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` to be handled you have to use the
>   `SecurityMiddleware`:
>
> ```
> MIDDLEWARE = [
>     ...
>     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
> ]
> ```

Note that both use

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

It seems that without this setting, it is not working on Heroku. And now comes the interesting/scary part. As explained in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-ssl-redirect):

> ### SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT
>
> ...
>
> If turning this to True causes infinite redirects, it probably means
>   your site is running behind a proxy and can’t tell which requests are
>   secure and which are not. Your proxy likely sets a header to indicate
>   secure requests; you can correct the problem by finding out what that
>   header is and configuring the `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` setting
>   accordingly.

Then, checking about [`SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER):

> **Warning**
>
> You will probably open security holes in your site if you set this
>   without knowing what you’re doing. And if you fail to set it when you
>   should. Seriously.

Which makes me want to find a safer solution... In [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539409) it says *it should be fine*, but I don't find it convincing enough to ignore such a warning.

Has Django really not any other solution that is **safe** to implement?

I am using version 1.11

---

Update:

I found the [django-sslify package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sslify), but it also requires setting `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')`, so I guess it doesn't make a difference in terms of potential security holes. Please, correct me if this assumption is wrong.

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682353) was actually posted last week, but there were no answers...

Comment: Just wanted to say that I have success with the package on Python 3.6.6/Django 2.1/Heroku/Gunicorn mix.

Comment: Could you write an answer expanding on how you made it? It could be helpful to many :)

Comment: Thanks for pinging me @J0ANMM.  It turns out there is still a possible issue. I pip installed Randall's work, configured per documentation (incl SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER for Heroku) and TBH the ONLY thing it solves was a redirection issue and https error free for www and no www.  The redirection of http to https did not work. Since I can't confirm if my app is the blocker or the code needs an update I went into my DNS (CloudFlare) and use a rule to fwd into https.  In downtime I plan on spinning up a test project on Heroku to confirm package operation, until then I am running.

Comment: I found this answer here, worked for me!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112662/10407102

Answer (score 0):

I think `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` is dangerous if you use it blindly because it makes Django think you are receiving an HTTPS request (even if `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` is, in fact, spoofed).

But, if you are behind a properly functioning load balance/proxy (like AWS) then you can be confident that `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` is being set correctly. In this case, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` serves to tell Django that it's fine, don't worry about it (because you are trusting the proxy to not allow through a spoofed header), and stop trying to continuously redirect to SSL.

Finally, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` behind a proxy/load balancer is necessary even if you **aren't** using `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` (e.g. if the redirection is happening in a properly configured web server before getting to Django), because it also affects the `is_secure()` function on the request, which would always be false if your proxy is swallowing the original request (e.g. it's common to go from HTTPS between the client and your proxy/load balancer to HTTP between your proxy/load balancer and a web server).

Source: [Django docs: SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER)